# How to store a set of lambdas in a polymorphic wrapper / container (without std::function)

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, stl

Is it possible to create a container that would keep different (capturing) lambdas in uniform way (we assume they have same operator() signature)

Please don't offer std::function as it uses virtual function call / heap alloc that is not necessary (instead I prefer just to copy the lambda by value)

For non capturing lambdas its easy because they decay to function pointers.

What I need to do is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename F>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(F f) : func(f) {}
    F func;
};

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    auto l = [x](int a, float b) {
        return a*b+x;
    };

    auto m = [x](int a, float b) {
        return a+b*x;
    };

    Wrapper<decltype(l)> aa(l);
    Wrapper<decltype(m)> bb(m);

    std::vector<decltype(aa)> v;
    v.push_back(aa);
    v.push_back(bb); // no matching member function
}
```

Right now the types of Wrapper(aa) and Wrapper(bb) are different. So I need to develop another Wrapper to put in std::vector.
What could it be? (no heap alloc? no vptr call?)

Comment: You want polymorphism essentially. Maybe CRTP? Another option is to consider converting (if applicable) the capturing lambdas to non-capturing (e.g., declare `(int a, int b, int x)` instead of `[x](int a, float b)` )

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername can you explain / give example of how to apply the CRTP here

Comment: If you were to limit this to capture-less lambdas, you might find a way. However, since each lambda will create a type, you are sorely out of luck on the polymorphism point. However, you can still get rid of the heap allocation by using small object optimization in `Wrapper`. There are quite a few implementation of std::function with SOO floating around.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the SOO tip it definitely should save some cpu cycles / atomic locks

Comment: @barney My recommendation to you (and anyone else considering doing this) is: make sure you agressively benchmark if you go down that road. A std::function with a larger `sizeof()` might negate any gains you get from dodging the heap. `malloc()` and `free()` are a LOT faster than most people given them credit for.